# php post to another page or the same?

Tags: php

I usually create another page to do my php posts like this:

page1.php:

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
...
</form>
```

page2.php:

```
<?php
$var = $_POST['...'];
?>
```

one friend of mine told me that I should to this in the same page:
page1.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['...'])){
...
}
else{
?>
   <form action="page1.php" method="post">
    ...
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

My question is, which one is a better or faster method and best practise?
thank you friends!

Comment: in terms of speed they are likely to be the same ( though if one script has 10 lines and another 10,000,000 lines then there would be a difference ) and as for which is better practise ~ that is personal preference and depends on the situation. Both give same results

Comment: My advice: don't ask, experiment! Try both ways and draw your own conclusion. Both ways have advantages and drawbacks.

Comment: IMHO the second option looks more promising as it has proper constraints to deal with exceptions and errors. You need to follow this approach in all of your php scripts to overcome any exceptions if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can do it in both the ways you have mentioned .

its not like you "*Should to this in the same page*"

In **first par**t you are passing the control from `page1` to `page2` ...which is done by submit button
So you can directly get the values using `$_POST['...'];`

Now in **seccond part** you are passing the **control to same page** , Since you are calling the same page on submit .

But here need to check if Post data has been set so for that you use **isset** method. 
**Most importantly** you can use second solution *if you want to **stay on the same page** after submission*

> Therefore, Use of **isset() method** in first part is a *good habbit* , but in
>   second solution is a **necessity**

*In my opinion Better use another page so that even the code does not look messed up.*

Comment: Except you should STILL use `isset();` or `empty();` on a submit to page2 as data might be missing / edited with malicious intend and cause your code to fail.

Comment: @Epodax :i totally agree with you that , i added that point to my answer thanks